# Why is WordPress loading blank pages on Nginx and PHP-FPM?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, php-fpm, arch-linux

Good day.

While this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/31834/php-cgi-started-serving-blank-pages) discusses a similar setup to mine serving blank pages occasionally after having made a successful installation, I am unable to serve anything but blank pages. There are no errors present in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, `/var/log/php-fpm.log` or `/var/log/nginx/us/sharonrhodes/blog/error.log`.

## My setup:

- Wordpress 3.0.4
- nginx 0.8.54
- php-fpm 5.3.5 (fpm-fcgi)
- Arch Linux

## Configuration Files

php-fpm.conf:

```
[global]
pid = run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = log/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice

[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0660
user = www
group = www

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.max_requests = 500
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog_sharonrhodes_us.conf:

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/us/sharonrhodes/blog/error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/us/sharonrhodes/blog/access.log;

    server_name blog.sharonrhodes.us;
    root /srv/apps/us/sharonrhodes/blog;
    index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content                                                                                        
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini                                                                                          
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass php;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect                                                                                         
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: blank page usually means there is a fatal error. Take a look at your error_log for more info

Comment: I should have stated this, but there are no errors present in /var/log/nginx/error.log, /var/log/php-fpm.log or /var/log/nginx/us/sharonrhodes/blog/error.log.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

By default the Nginx source does not define SCRIPT_FILENAME in the fastcgi_params file, so unless the repo you installed Nginx from does that you need to do it yourself.

Check if the following line is in your fastcgi_params file:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

and if not then add it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` defined right at the top of `/etc/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf`. I will edit the original post to reflect this.

Comment: You include the file fastcgi_params, not fastcgi.conf. My answer is still valid.

Answer (score 5):

This one just bit me- and it was totally my fault. I wanted to share what fixed me.  In my case, the index.php wasn't loading (blank page) but wp-admin worked.

I have a custom theme and I recently migrated from a shared hosting account to a VPS.  I did an rsync and my theme (/srv/blog.clifton.io/wp-content/themes/theme-here) is a symlink. This symlink broke of course, since it was using the path from my previous hosting account.

Hope this helps! (and wish it would log "THEME NOT FOUND" or similar)

Comment: spent 2 days on it. Deleted a theme unknowingly and there were blank pages. I should definitely show a theme not found error.