# "Image cannot be processed." Cryptic Wordpress error when uploading new header image

Tags: nginx, wordpress, arch-linux

When I attempt to upload a new header image to my wordpress installation my browser's work is acknowledged with a cryptic "Image could not be processed. Please go back and try again." The upload *does* succeed: `wp-content/uploads/.../header.jpg` exists as it should.

There are no error messages in /var/log/messages--which php is configured to log errors to--nor in nginx's error log. This setup was previously discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/223500/blank-page-wordpress-on-nginxphp-fpm).

## My setup:

- Wordpress 3.0.4
- Twenty Ten 1.1
- nginx 0.8.54
- php-fpm 5.3.5 (fpm-fcgi)
- Arch Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might not have the gd library installed and enabled in php.  I'm not much of an Linux guy, but I did this to get it installed on my setup:

```
yum install php-gd
```

Here's some more about it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=506801

Don't forget to restart httpd after installing gd.